# Passing a v-model variable to another variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this componentfrom algolia

```html
<ais-configure 
  :hitsPerPage="3"
  :filters="filters"
/>
```

I am trying to pass the filters variable and i can do that like this

```js
filters:'rd_property_region:"London"'
```

and this works.

I would like to have the city part dynamic so in my data section i have intoruced a v-model city and i a trying to access it

```js
city:"New York",
filters:'rd_property_region:`${this.city}`'
```

but the city is not being passed.

How should I pass the city variable to my filter variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you actually want to use a computed property

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    city: "New York"
  }),
  computed: {
    filters: ({ city }) => `rd_property_region:"${city}"`
  }
}
```

Here's a simple demo...

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    city: "New York"
  }),
  computed: {
    filters: ({ city }) => `rd_property_region:"${city}"`
  }
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="city">
    <option>London</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>New York</option>
  </select>
  <pre>filters = {{ filters }}</pre>
</div>
```

---

There were several problems with your initial code.

If you were wanting to interpolate `city` into the `filters` string, the format should be one of the following:

- Template literal

  ```js
  `rd_property_region:"${city}"`
  ```
- Concatenation

  ```js
  'rd_property_region:"' + city + '"'
  ```

Keep in mind though that this will not be reactive to changes in `city` and if you try and do this within the `data` function return value, `this.city` will be `undefined` when `filters` is evaluated. Your only real option for a static, non-reactive `data` function would be something like this

```js
data: () => {
  const data = { city: "New York" }
  return { ...data, filters: `rd_property_region:"${data.city}"` }
}
```

Comment: I don understand this `filters: `rd_property_region:"${this.city}"`` this goes in computed as well?

Comment: @Gandalf I don't understand your question but the last part of my answer shows you exactly what goes in `data` and what goes in `computed`

Comment: The second part is correct and works. However, in template literal and concatenation, i would like to know where this would go, inside data and not inside computed?

Comment: @Gandalf that was just an example of how you get one string inside another. In this particular instance, you cannot define `data` properties like that since `this.city` will be `undefined` when the `filters` string is evaluated

Comment: This worked ` filters: function () {return `rd_property_region:"${this.city}"`}` as well.

Comment: @Gandalf it's functionally identical, I just prefer the shorter version